# Compiling nodeJs project on windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, design-patterns

i'm developing a nodeJs application and i'm new with node, since I need to use the GOF design patterns I am creating the typescript classes first and then I need to compile them in order to generate the equivalent Javascript code.
On linux a friend of mine that share a project with me uses commands on this script

```
"scripts": {
   "test": "npm run com && npm run exe",
   "com": "./node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc",
   "exe": "node dist/server.js"
 },
```

but in my laptop with windows 10 does not work if i call the command `npm run com && npm run exe`...does anyone have suggestions on how to compile?
My project on my pc is under `E:\Università\Specialistica\PrimoAnno\IngegneriaSoftware\Progetto-Software-Engineering`

Thanks to all :-)

Comment: Define `it does not work`? ["It's not working" is not helpful](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)

Comment: i mean it doesn't compile me from typescript to javascript when i run the above commands `npm run com && npm run exe`

Comment: But are you getting an error?

Comment: Yes, this is my error:
```
> npm run com && npm run exe
npm notice 
npm notice New minor version of npm available! 7.0.3 -> 7.9.0       
npm notice Changelog: https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v7.9.0
npm notice Run npm install -g npm@7.9.0 to update!
npm notice 
> software_eng_project@1.0.0 com   
> ./node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc
"." non è riconosciuto come comando interno o esterno,
 un programma eseguibile o un file batch.
```

Comment: The OP obviously didn't read the link you provided @JeremyThille. I have voted to close this issue since the author did not provide enough detail to debug this issue. Ezio please read the link JeremyThille posted above and also read the [help].

Comment: @CharlieFish I described the problem as it appeared, it was enough to ask for more info if necessary, without necessarily closing the post.
anyway thanks for  your precious help ;-)

Comment: The error says you haven't installed Typescript, so you don't have the typescript compiler (tsc) avaiable. Just try `npm i` which should install everything from your `package.json`. You see, if you had explained us everything, meaning providing the error message instead of just saying "It doesn't work", it would have been much easier

Comment: @JeremyThille thanks, i've installed typescript and now i've only this error ` npm run com && npm run exe


> software_eng_project@1.0.0 com   
> ./node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc

"." non è riconosciuto come comando interno o esterno,
 un programma eseguibile o un file batch.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path E:\Università\Specialistica\PrimoAnno\IngegneriaSoftware\Progetto-Software-Engineering
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c "./node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc"
.`
I think because i've windows, but i'm not sure

Comment: Just try `"com" : "tsc"` then. If it's installed globally, tsc should be available directly as a command line tool.